# .NET Controller Action sometimes returns undefined and doesn't post form

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

After upgrading to .NET 6 I'm having a strange issue with one of my apps. The submit button doesn't always fire.  Most of the time it does, but on occasion, it will not. It's very frustrating and I cant see to pinpoint the issue.

I've tried removing all jquery/javascript, but the issue persists. If I output the value of res.IsValid,  For some reason, every now then, it will return "Undefined", instead of true or false. I've also confirmed that ModalState is valid. I've also tried moving this into a standard page vs. modal popup and removing the onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);" fro the form, but no change.

the function is pretty basic as it's just a modal popup that allows you to link up similar programs by selecting from a drop down list. Its pretty basic really.  Here is the code.   When the issue does occur, I usually have to click the submit multiple times, and then it fires:

Controller:

```
               public async Task<IActionResult> AssociatedSystemsEntry(int programId)
        {
            ProjectAssociationViewModel vm = new ProjectAssociationViewModel()
            {
                ProgramId = programId,
                ListOfPrograms = await _programSrv.GetProgramsAvailableForLinkingAsync(programId)
            };
            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AssociatedSystemsEntry(ProjectAssociationViewModel vm)
        {
            ViewBag.Permission = true;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                vm.ListOfPrograms = await _programSrv.GetProgramsAvailableForLinkingAsync(vm.ProgramId);

                return Json(new { isValid = false, view = "", html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "AssociatedSystemsEntry", vm) });

            }
           await _programSrv.LinkProgramAsync(vm.ProgramId, vm.SelectedProgramId ?? 0);

            //  if valid, reset value and re-show popup
            return Json(new { isValid = true, view = "associatedSystemsView", html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_AssociatedSystems", await _programSrv.GetAssociatedSystemsByProgramAsync(vm.ProgramId)) });

        }
```

Jquery Code:

```
jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.action,
        data: new FormData(form),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (res) {

         
            if (res.isValid) {

                if (res.view != null && res.html != null) {
                    $('#' + res.view).html(res.html);
                }

                $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
            }
            else {

                $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
                $('#form-modal .modal-title').html(title);
                $('#form-modal').modal('show');
               

            }


        },
        fail: function (err) {
            alert(err.responseText);
        }
        ,
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.responseText);
        }
    })
    //to prevent default form submit event

  
    return false;
}
```

Razor Code:

```
<form asp-action="AssociatedSystemsEntry" asp-controller="Program" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProgramId" />


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.SelectedProgramId" class="control-label"></label><span class="text-danger">*</span>

                <select class="form-control" asp-items="Model.ListOfPrograms" asp-for="@Model.SelectedProgramId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ProgramId" class="text-danger" style="color:red;"></span>

                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.SelectedProgramId" class="text-danger" style="color:red;"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" id="btn-upload" class="btn btn-dark text-white mt-4">Save</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Database

```
        public async Task LinkProgramAsync(int programId, int associatedProgram)
    {
        var list = new List<ProjectAssociation>();

        if (!await _projectMappingRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.ChildId == associatedProgram && x.ParentId == programId).AnyAsync())
        {
            list.Add(new ProjectAssociation
            {
                ChildId = associatedProgram,
                ParentId = programId
            });

        }

        if (!await _projectMappingRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.ChildId == programId && x.ParentId == associatedProgram).AnyAsync())
        {
            list.Add(new ProjectAssociation
            {
                ChildId = programId,
                ParentId = associatedProgram
            });

        }

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            _projectMappingRepo.Insert(item);
        }
        await _projectMappingRepo.SaveAsync();

    }
```

Comment: Smells like a race condition. Maybe you have an unawaited task somewhere?

Comment: i posted the method that updates the database up above. Is there a better way to write this? I'm new to the whole task/async functionality.